# Make connection to Solr with PHP

Tags: php, solr, xsd, schema

I've just installed Solr and I got the default schema working with me. But when I change the schema from the default to simplier one, I cannot connect through solr through php but can through tomcat still. My php code looks like this:

```
require_once 'Apache/Solr/Service.php';

        $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service(
        'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx',
        8080,
        '/dev.example.com/');

        if(!$solr->ping()){         
            echo 'Solr Down';
        }
```

And my schema in solr

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema name="testschema1" version="1.5">
  <types>
   <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
  </types>

 <fields>
  <!-- general -->
  <field name="id"  type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" required="true"/>
  <field name="type"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
  <field name="name"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
  <field name="core0"   type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
 </fields>

 <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

Also I get this error when I use java -jar start.jr

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:408)
```

Just to clarify, it only does not connect from PHP when I change the schema to the one above, the default schema provided by solr works. Am I missing some required option?

Answer (score 2):

Seems the text field is referenced several times in solrconfig.xml (I found this post through the same error). You can update those references to the field name of your choice (whatever makes sense in your schema).

Doing that fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution here.  Seems 'better' than having to add an arbitrary unused `text` field to the schema to satisfy the error message, but be cautious of updates to Solr that may replace your `solrconfig.xml` customisations.

Comment: True that, my solrconfig.xml is highly customized, and bringing it inline with what Apache Solr uses is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you try to connect with solr it is looking for a field called `text` which is missing from your schema.

Add the following line to your schema and try again:

```
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Not sure that makes much sens sense, the default field is set to :<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>